Removing intercept and parameter from ADL model
I have a problem when I'm trying to construct an ADL(1,3) using the dLagM package. The problem is I want to remove both the $X_t$ and the intercept, since both have a p-value over 0.05. But when I'm trying to do it. It either removes the Intercept or the X_t. Therefore I would like to ask if any of you could help me with this problem, so both get removes from the model. I have already tried reading the documentation of the package, but it did not help me either. My code is shown below
# Define your data
x <- var_data_chow$Electricity_price
y <- var_data_chow$Electricity_consumption


# Parameters to remove
rem.p <- 0 # 0 removes the main effect of X.t 
rem.q <- -1 # remove lagged terms

# Create the remove list
remove <- list(p = rem.p, q = rem.q)

# Adjusted model with parameters removed
model.ardl <- ardlDlm(x = x, y = y, p = 1, q = 3, remove = remove,)


# Display the summary of the adjusted model
summary(model.ardl)

I have already tried to read the documentation of the R-package and tried to change the parameters and use -1 minus for the rem.q, as the documentation said would solve the problem, which it did not.

Before I offer an answer I am compelled to point out that what you are doing is a very bad idea. You say:

The problem is I want to remove both the $X_t$ and the intercept, since both have a p-value over 0.05

Please, please, please do not remove variables (including the intercept) from your model just because the p-value is above some arbitrary threshold. This is very bad practice and only leads to bias of varying kinds. There is a wealth of information regarding this topic on SO's sister site Cross Validated. If you really need to do this then you could use this code, or a variation of it:
library(dLagM)
library(dynlm)

set.seed(123)

n <- 100  # Number of observations
time <- 1:n

electricity_price <- 0.5 * time + rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 2)
electricity_consumption <- 2 * electricity_price + rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 3)


var_data_chow <- data.frame(Electricity_price = electricity_price, Electricity_consumption = electricity_consumption)

x <- var_data_chow$Electricity_price
y <- var_data_chow$Electricity_consumption

# Lagged variables
y_lag1 <- c(NA, y[-length(y)])
y_lag2 <- c(NA, NA, y[-(length(y)-1):-(length(y))])
y_lag3 <- c(NA, NA, NA, y[-(length(y)-2):-(length(y))])
x_lag1 <- c(NA, x[-length(x)])

data <- data.frame(y = y, y_lag1 = y_lag1, y_lag2 = y_lag2, y_lag3 = y_lag3, x_lag1 = x_lag1)

# Remove rows with NA values
data <- na.omit(data)

# Fit the model without intercept and main effect of X.t
model <- dynlm(y ~ y_lag1 + y_lag2 + y_lag3 - 1, data = data)

summary(model)




